# how set default date in alloyui date picker in alloy ui 2.0.x version

Tags: datepicker, alloy-ui, liferay-6.2

I want set default date in alloy ui datepicker.
in previous version 1.5.x that is dates attribute in calendar.

```
new A.DatePickerSelect(
   {
    appendOrder: ['m', 'd', 'y'],
      calendar: {
      dates: ['10/01/2014'] // in 1.5.x version to set default date which is diplayed on textbox of date picker
    }
  }
).render('#myDatePicker');
```

version 1.5.x : http://alloyui.com/versions/1.5.x/examples/datepicker/

is there any alternative to achieve thing in alloy ui 2.0.x version. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dates attribute is deprecated in version 2.0.x

alternative of that thing is 'selectDates(..)' method.

```
function(Y) {
var datepicker = new Y.DatePicker(
  { 
    trigger: '#presentationDate',
    popover: {
            zIndex: 1
        },
    ...... 
  }
 datepicker.selectDates(new Date()); // set default date in version 2.0.x using date picker object.
```